# How to properly record my guitar over a backing track of a song?

Tags: electric-guitar, recording

I have learned quite a few songs and practiced them along with the track. Since I'm new to recording, i want to properly record my guitar part over a backing track of that song which i have been practicing and make it sound decent i.e. mixed very well with the backing track. I have reaper and fruityloops as my DAW.

**Update**: I want to record Electric guitar and planning to use Multi-effects/amp-modelling pedal.

Answer (score 2):

Is it an electric or acoustic guitar ?

If acoustic:
First is to get a reasonably good microphone. This depends on your budget, and "you get what you pay for" right from a few tens of £ / $ up to hundreds or more.

However there are two main types: Dynamic and Condenser.

Dynamic microphones are generally good for picking up things relatively close by like a voice or an electric guitar amp, but some are good for all-round use.

Condenser mics are generally better at more ambient recordings so if you're recording an acoustic guitar, that might be a better option. A lot of condenser mics use "Phantom power" which is most easily supplied by your mixer. It'd be worth looking into that before choosing which type.

If electric guitar:
You can either mic our amp up for recording (usually best bet as you probably have a sound you like already) OR a lot of effects units have a built-in "Amp simulator" meaning you can plug directly from the effects unit into your DAW - no microphone needed. the Amp Simulator electronically adds the kind of effect you get when you record an amp through a microphone.

Line1 and Pod make such things, and have a good reputation, though other makes have probably nailed it.

I assume reaper and fruityloops can "Multitrack" so if your backing track doesn't exist in them yet, import that first as your first track.
Then by whatever means record your guitar ans an extra track.

You should then be able to play the two together and amend the volume / effects on each so that it sounds how you like it.

Mixing tracks is an artform in itself (best search for topics on that) but if you have "everything but guitar" on one track and your guitar on another, then really you're just amending your guitar volume according to everything else, so should be fairly easy to get a good mix.

To give you a clue of how you're doing, have a listen to a track where you like the guitar part and try to get close to that.

One thing which can catch people by surprise: "Studio tan" .. after a while of mixing you may find you've been listening to it so intensely that you've lost sight of what's good. If this happens, take a break.
Have a cuppa, etc :-)

Comment: I have the backing track on one track and the guitar track on another so how do i mix them ? is mixing all about meddling the EQ's ?

Comment: I'm assuming the backtrack has no guitars in it. In that case you just put the guitar on one track and the backtrack on another and they will mix just fine by themselves.

Comment: Mixing = adjusting of volume of the tracks (backing vs guitar) so that they 'sit' nicely together and one isn't drowning the other out, plus  the EQ of each track so that one isn't more bringht than the other (or bassy etc) - plus sometimes some effects eg reverb on guitar or maybe compression over both tracks afer they're merged, whcih kind of brings the whole thing together. Hope that helps, and hope you enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a good microphone. A decent microphone that is used a lot to mic amps is the Shure SM57. Loads of tutorials on Youtube describe how you should mic your amp.
Then with the aid of the backing track in you headphones, you should record yourself.
Afterwards put the 2 tracks together in your program (Fruityloops or ...).

Comment: I have a multi-effects/amp-modelling pedal which I'm planning to use rather than a mic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it in the form of a blog post: http://www.osirisguitar.com/three-ways-to-record-electric-guitars/